# Is it possible to scale up windowed SpaceChem?

Tags: spacechem

I like spacechem, and I like playing it windowed, but it's too small windowed, and I can't seem to find a way to scale it up (more pixels). Any tricks for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum resolution appears to be 1024x768

For confirmation, navigate to the following directory on your computer:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Zachtronics Industries\SpaceChem
```

Edit `config.ini` and change the `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` options.

This will adjust the size of the window, but unfortunately, the actual pixels of the game do not scale to fill the window.

[image: spacechem, scaled down]

*(As a side note, the first splash screen that reads "A Game By Zachtronics Industries" does scale very nicely up to a very high resolution.)*

Comment: This also helped answer my question "how do I get SpaceChem to correctly launch full-screen" (`windowWidth` and `windowHeight` were waaaaaaaaay higher than 1024x768, so I reset them to that and it's now filling at least one dimension of the screen again)